# Parent background color showing on right and bottom with a child 100% width & height

Tags: html, css

I have 3 issues:

1. I can see a part of the parent white background bottom (& right side sometimes) under its child that have a 100% width & height (see green arrow on my screenshot)
2. The child width is set to 100% but when i inspect it is larger than the parent (see the red arrow on the screenshot)
3. My line-height is `line-height:30px;` and my `font-size:30px;` but there is a different spacing on top and bottom of the text (see the blues arrows on my screenshot). This prevent me from centering correctly vertically my text

Note: My browser zoom is on 100%

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gr85n2es/

[image]

Comment: for the (3) add uppercase letters and you will understand that the sape is not different

Comment: Ok but what if i don't use an uppercase? i still want my text to be centered vertically

Comment: it's *already* centred .. and what if you will not use letter like `g` or `t`? how to deal with `aes` or `lop`  or `jqp`?